# How to calculate total price of an order with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the order list built up like so:

**order.rb**

```
has_many :line_products
```

**LineProduct.rb**

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
```

and has a value for `count` and a relationship for product (which is where it's getting the price from).

So it goes like this:

```
product #1 has a price of $ 5.00
product #2 has a price of $ 3.50

line_product #1 has a count of 3 (so that's 3*5=15 USD)
line_product #2 has a count of 6 (so that's 6*3.50=21 USD)
```

And I need, for the order show view, calculate the sum of `15 and 21`, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate through the association collection, and use a method like `reduce` to calculate the sum:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_products

  def total_price
    @total_price ||= line_products.includes(:product).reduce(0) do |sum, l_prod|
      sum + (l_prod.count * l_prod.product.price)
    end
  end
end
```

Just remember to:

- eager load the nested association with `.includes(:product)`, to minimize the number of DB queries,
- memoize the return value with `@ivar ||=`, so that you won't have to recalculate it every time you query the same object.

Comment: What will happen really here with @total_price ? Is it keeped for whole of whole controller action ? What if the product price change between two calls to same instance ?

Comment: This method will set `@total_price` the first time it is invoked, to memoize the result of the calculation, and then not touch it again. Other methods could reset the value (like busting a cache).

Answer (score 0):

Create sum method for LineProduct

```rails
def sum
  product.price * count # I believe you have count/price validations in place
end
```

`order.line_products.map(&:sum).inject(:+)`

`inject(:+)` is for summing up

Comment: This will work, but it's very inefficient, as it will execure a new DB query for each `line_product`.

Comment: @tompave could you show an example of how to do it more efficiently?

Comment: of course tom, adding includes(:product) will pre-load product to memory, this is just very basic answer for very basic question.